# change only if input field is not focused (input event)

Tags: jquery, events, input

```js
$(document).on('click', '#register-continue', function() {
  $('.modal-register-form :input[type=text], .modal-register-form :input[type=email], .modal-register-form :input[type=password]').each(function() {
    $(this).on('input', function() {
      if ($(this).val().length) {
        $(this).css({
          border: '1px solid #e5e5e5'
        });
      } else {
        $(this).css({
          border: '1px solid #fe0000'
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-register-form">
  <div class="user-input">
    <input class="first-name" type="text" placeholder="first name">
    <input class="last-name" type="text" placeholder="last name">
  </div>
  <button type="button" id="register-continue" class="register">continue</button>
</div>
```

Hi,

Does anyone know, how to change the border color only if the input field is not focused. Currently, it changes if it's focued. Additionally, the border should change the color as well at the start of the function if an input is empty.

Thank you for your support.

Best regards

Comment: You want the default border the browser adds to the input field disabled and instead you want a border that disappears if the input is on focus?

Answer (score 1):

Delegate the `focus` and `blur` events using `.on()` method and set the two styles on a condition since the `input` will either be focused or unfocused. If you want an initial border style, you CSS. The following demo will change the border of an input to blue on `focus` event, red on `blur` event and initially as well.

---

### Demo

```js
$('input').on('focus blur', function(e) {
  if (e.type === 'focus') {
    $(this).css('border', '1px solid #e5e5e5');
  } else {
    $(this).css('border', '1px solid #fe0000');
  }
});
```

```css
input,
button {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

input {
  border: 1px solid #fe0000;
  width: 39%;
  padding: 3px;
}
```

```html
<form class="modal-register-form">
  <fieldset class="user-input">
    <input class="first-name" type="text" placeholder="first name">
    <input class="last-name" type="text" placeholder="last name">
    <button type="button" id="register-continue" class="btn register">Continue</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on how I understood your question:

Your code isn't working because you are trying to get an event in an event. just make a second event for the `keyup`. The css prevent the default browser focus behaivor.

You can change the event on whatever you like

```js
var selector = $('.modal-register-form :input[type=text], .modal-register-form :input[type=email], .modal-register-form :input[type=password]');

$(document).on('click', '#register-continue', function() {
  selector.each(function() {
      changeColor($(this));
  });
});

selector.on('focus focusout keyup', function() {
    changeColor($(this));
});


function changeColor(elm) {
if (elm.val().length) {
        elm.css({
          border: '1px solid #e5e5e5'
        });
      } else {
        elm.css({
          border: '1px solid #fe0000'
        });
      }
}
```

```css
.modal-register-form input {
  outline-width: 0;
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal-register-form">
  <div class="user-input">
    <input class="first-name" type="text" placeholder="first name">
    <input class="last-name" type="text" placeholder="last name">
  </div>
  <button type="button" id="register-continue" class="register">continue</button>
</div>
```

**If I understood your question wrong, just give me a comment and I'll add my answer!**